# OpenId sign-in screen like stackoverflow

Tags: php, openid

I am looking for an example of an openId sign-in just like stackoverlow.  I saw a few around, but I don't like the idea of copying or memorizing a url to enter.  I want to include options for openId with google/yahoo/etc buttons.

I said something about not liking the standard openid login, however, that will be there as an example.  I am more interested in lining openid with google, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a near duplicate question to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702114/stackoverflow-like-login-system-in-rails/704067

Although this question is PHP and that one is Rails, the UI of the login that you're asking about is web server language agnostic.